# What's the best way (performance-wise) to publish mercurial repositories on a windows server?

Tags: mercurial

I have the impression that hg server is rather slow on our Windows Server... Are there better ways to publish mercurial repositories?

Comment: Since you're asking for methods with better performance than what you're currently using, it would be useful to provide more details about your current hosting solution.  There are various aspects of how a given server is configured and used that can result in performance problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list that compares the possibilities for publishing repositories can be found [here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories).

I'd recommend [hgweb](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories#hgweb), which is probably the most flexible solution also on Windows. You can use it with [Apache](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories#ConfiguringApache) or [IIS](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgWebInIisOnWindows).